# Setting mapZoom programatically in highcharts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to create custom zoom in/out buttons and I've got it working except for the most important part, the zooming..

I've created a map chart like this:

```
$scope.chart = new Highcharts.Map(config);
```

Then I have two functions which run whenever you click on zoom in or out:

```
highcharts.zoomIn = function() {
  $scope.chart.mapZoom(0.5);
};

highcharts.zoomOut = function() {
  $scope.chart.mapZoom(2);
};
```

Setting the `mapZoom` of the chart doesn't give me an error nor does it do anything. I tried calling `$scope.chart.redraw()` afterwards but it didn't help either. Also saw that it already calls the redraw function in the source code of the `mapZoom` function.

I can't find any information on how to do this so what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked if clicking zoom in and out buttons works? I mean some console.log()? It should work well, maybe this example will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/akrLLpwe/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Yes they run and they do update the mapZoom but the chart ain't refreshing :/

Comment: Thank for this info. Could you post working example of this issue?